# Batch Script - Next Largest Number After X?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, numbers

Ok, I'm making a .bat file and i've made most of it. All I need to do now is to make the Batch file search in a folder for the next largest number after X and then the next largest number after that and I want that number to be stored as a variable, E.g. :
 I have a folder with the files:
2.txt, 4.txt, 6.txt, and 8.txt. If X=2, then I would like it to find the next largest number, which is four, then the next largest number after that, which is 6. And I would like '6' or '6.txt' to be saved as a variable so I can use it later.
So if my files are 10, 20, 30 and 40.txt and X=10, the outcome would be '30' or '30.txt' stored as a variable.

I have tried googling this and I have any found questions like 'Find the LARGEST numbered text file.' My question is the NEXT largest and then the one AFTER that.

Thanks to anyone in advance who helps me!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

not tested:

```
@echo off

set "root_dir=."
set "number=15"

pushd "%root_dir%"
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b^|findstr /i /r "[0-9]*[^a-zA-Z]\.txt$"') do (
    if %%~nf GTR %number% (
       set "next=%%~nxf"
       goto :break_for
    )
)
:break_for
echo %next%
```

Comment: Didn't work, it just outputs the largest number in the directory, does 'SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion' affect this script in any way? Because i've put that code in my batch script.

Comment: @flamebull5 - I've edited my post .The delayed expansion wont help.I've forgot to put a break for the loop. Check in now.